# How to properly call Javascript Function from Gridview Selected Index Changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, scriptmanager

I have a User Control --> Aspx Page--> Master Page scenario. The User Control contains a GridView. I want to be able to call a javascript function when the Gridview "Select" linkbutton is clicked.

I am able to get this to work the first time the linkbutton is clicked, but every other subsequent click fails to call the javascript function.

I am currently registering my javascript function using the ASP.Net ScriptManager/ScriptManagerProxy method - [Proper way to use JQuery when using MasterPages in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731407/proper-way-to-use-jquery-when-using-masterpages-in-asp-net)

Any ideas on why this fails after the first try?

Comment: Please include some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code I'm not sure your implementation, but here's what I'd do:

`LinkButton`, like `Button` has an `OnClientClick` property that you can set to call client-side JavaScript before running the PostBack.  But you don't have access to this when you are using a `CommandField`.

First, convert your `CommandField` (the one with the Select button) to a `TemplateField`.  You should then be given a `LinkButton` or `Button`, which you can then set the `OnClientClick` property for.

I think this would be a lot simpler than doing registerscripts, etc.